# C# SignalR : Issues updating data from code-behind

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket, signalr

.

I have a back-end application (running .net c#) and a front-end application running on node and VUE.JS 2.

The Front-end is posting new orders, and the "dashboard" in the back-end solution should automatically fetch new incoming orders using SignalR.

I have it about 90% correct, but having issues updating the client with the data. (Current code is actually running in a loop, fetching new data all the time).

So how do i "force" a update of the client from back-end the correct way ?

**Javascript- /FrontEnd code :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // start hub
    var orderHub = $.connection.orderHub;
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        console.log("Orderhub initialized...");
    });
    // end hub

    var OrdersModel = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.orders = ko.observableArray();
    }
    var ordersmodel = new OrdersModel();

    orderHub.client.updateOrders = function (orders) {
        orderHub.server.getOrders().then(
            result => {
                ordersmodel.orders(result);
            }
        ); 
        console.log("Getting updated orders : " + orders);
    }

    ko.applyBindings(ordersmodel, document.getElementById("ordersContainer"));

    $.get('api/Order',
        function (data) {
            ordersmodel.orders(data);
            console.log("API kall - GetOrders");
        }, 'json');
});
```

**Orderhub.cs code :**

```
public void GetOrders()
    {
        var loggedInCompany = 2;
        var orders = OrderServices.GetNewestOrdersAsVM(loggedInCompany);
        Clients.All.updateOrders(orders);
    }
```

**POST call from front-end (triggers update) :**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] OrderViewModel newOrder)
    {
        var result = OrderServices.SaveNewOrderFromVM(newOrder);

        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<OrderHub>();
        context.Clients.All.updateOrders();

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Here is an article that shows how to subscribe to events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#how-to-establish-a-connection. An important thing is to remember that you need to subscribe to at least one event before you start the connection

Answer (score 0):

It all looks correct except in your controller, you call `updateOrders()` with no parameters, whereas your client side callback expects orders. In your Post action, you actually need to run:

```
var loggedInCompany = 2;
var orders = OrderServices.GetNewestOrdersAsVM(loggedInCompany);
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<OrderHub>();
context.Clients.All.updateOrders(orders);
```

I generally use my SignalR hub just for maintaining the connected clients for scenarios where I need to interact with specific clients or when you want a method on the server that can be invoked by clients. For handling all my SignalR interactions, I use a wrapper class.